# R, both side closed break

Tags: r

I want to define the following 3 breaks in R: `[0,45) [45,55] (55,Inf)`

I have definied vector and I tried:

`cut(vector, c(0, 45, 55, Inf), include.lowest=TRUE, right=FALSE)`

but I get that breaks: `[0,45) [45,55) [55,Inf]`

I can't figure it out how to get a both side closed break. Furthermore I don't know how to get 3 breaks opened and closed in different ways. How can I get it?

Comment: You can specify it in `labels` i.e `labels = c("[0,45)", "[45,55]", "(55,Inf)")`

Comment: You need just `cut(vector, c(0, 45, 55, Inf), include.lowest=TRUE, right=FALSE, labels = c("[0,45)", "[45,55]", "(55,Inf)"))`

Comment: Right, I didn't saw your edit before. Thank you a lot @akrun!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can override the default output format with a custom format in `labels` argument

```
cut(vector, c(0, 45, 55, Inf), include.lowest = TRUE, 
    right = FALSE, labels = c("[0,45)", "[45,55]", "(55,Inf)"))
```